# matplotlib, set color of lines along a grayscale using numbers from 0. (white) to 1. (black)

Tags: python, matplotlib, grayscale

I've been trying to follow [the instructions here](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html) to set the color of many lines along a grayscale using floats from `0.` (white) to `1.` (black). The function `line.set_color()` accepts the floats, but the error below appears when I do `plt.show()`:

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "1.0"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "1.0"
cannot convert argument to rgb sequence
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13973528/832621) it is explained how to do that using `plt.cm.RdYlBu(i)`. Is there any equivalent for grayscale?

Comment: Do you simply want to construct a white-to-black colormap?

Comment: Sure, just `plt.cm.gray` (or `plt.cm.gray_r` if you want it going the other way.  See the colormaps here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/show_colormaps.html

Comment: Also, the error is because matplotlib uses _strings_ of floats to indicate grayscale instead of actual floats.  So you'd pass in `'0.5`' instead of `0.5`.  (That's one of the more confusing corners of things. It's for reasons I won't get into here, but it's a common gotcha.  There's no technical reason why it can't just accept a single float--it's just historical.)

Comment: Thank you! you could add this comment as the answer...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For historical reasons, `matplotlib` expects "floats" to be interpreted as grayscale values to be passed in as strings, which is the reason for your error.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10), color="0.5")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Also, for a grayscale colormap, just use `plt.cm.gray` or `plt.cm.gray_r` (reversed).  There's a full list of colormaps here: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/show_colormaps.html