# Change colour of curve according to its y-value in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, color-mapping

I'm trying to replicate the style of the attached figure using matplotlib's facilities.

[image: Curves whose colour change with height]

Basically, I want to change the colour of the curve according to its y-value using matplotlib.

Comment: It's not clear what sets the color in your example.  There must be some third value, because the color is clearly not set by the value of `c\tau/R_0` nor `kR_0`.

Comment: For more information, see [Having line color vary with data index for line graph in matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13972287/having-line-color-vary-with-data-index-for-line-graph-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The plot you've shown doesn't have the color set by the vertical axis of the plot (which is what I would consider the *y-value*).  Instead, it just has 8 different plots overlain, each with a different color, without stating what the color means.

Here's an example of something that looks like your plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

# some fake data:
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
fs = np.arange(1, 5.)
ys = np.sin(x*fs[:, None])

for y, f in zip(ys, fs):
    plt.plot(x, y, lw=3, c=cm.hot(f/5))
```

[image: colors]

If you actually want the color of one line to change with respect to its value, you have to kind of hack it, because any given `Line2D` object can only have one color, as far as I know.  One way to do this is to make a scatter plot, where each dot can have any color.

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
y = np.sin(2*x)
plt.scatter(x,y, c=cm.hot(np.abs(y)), edgecolor='none')
```

Notes:

- The color vector should range between `0` and `1`, so if `y.max() > 1`, then normalize by it: `c=cm.hot(y/y.max())` and make sure it's all positive.
- I used `edgecolor='none'` because by default the `scatter` markers have a black outline which makes the it look less like a uniform line.
- If your data is spaced too far, you'll have to interpolate the data if you don't want gaps between markers.

[image: more colors]

Comment: Right you are. Forgetting the plot, however, do you have an idea of how to change the colour of the line according to the position on the vertical axis?

Comment: In matplotlib, one line object cannot have more than one color. The best approximation to what you want is to do a scatter plot where the color is set by the same values as the y array.  I'll edit my answer soon to give an example.

Comment: How should I show the colorbar in this case?